# XSLT: Is it possible to use resulting tag value for calculation of next tag?

Tags: xml, xslt

Given we have some XSLT transformation which transforms XML A into XML B.

During this process some field B.a is populated basing on some rules by our transformation.

After this we want to populate B.b. But the rules of that field population are based on B.a value! So we need to do this is a consequtive manner and use B.a value in next calculations.

Is it possible in XSLT?

Comment: Maybe using `xsl:variable`? A concrete example would help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, it comes down to following this pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <!-- get the result -->
   <xsl:copy-of select="$b.b" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="$b.a">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc('a.xml')" mode="a" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="$b.b">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc('b.xml')" mode="b" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="some/node/in/a" mode="a">
   <!-- do your thing here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="some/node/in/b[$b.a/based/on/a[@x]]" mode="b">
   <!-- do your thing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

If you are unfortunate and stuck with XSLT 1.0 for some reason, use exslt:node-set() on the variables when re-applying nodes to them. Also, you will have to make the difference in that case in the selections, instead of in the (preferred) matching templates pattern expressions, because patterns in XSLT 1.0 cannot use variable references.